How do I create a 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi network with my Windows 11 PC from a 5 GHz Wi-Fi connection?
My office is in a university building. We only have eduroam Wi-Fi, working on 5 GHz. My 3D printer only receives 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi, so I'm trying to set up a hotspot with my PC.
I bought two of the same Wi-Fi cards, in hopes that this would work - but so far no luck.
What do I need to do to make this work?

You bought to wireless cards: what did you do with them? Please list exactly what you've tried so far and put this information in the question itself. This information, and anything else you can think to add, will go a long way towards making your question more clear and complete, and getting you a better chance of getting good answers.


If you press Win+I.
On the left column go to Network and Internet.
Click on the third element called Mobile Hotspot.
Then click on the properties toggle arrow pointing down
click on the 'Edit' button.
Then change the 'Network Band' to suit your needs.

